# How to get the values of `textField` in the "Father" component

Tags: reactjs, redux, material-ui

I set a `material-ui/TextField` in my user-defined `component`. The user-defined `component` is named `LabelTextField`. I render several `LabelTextField` in my user-defined `component` which is named `TextList`. My question is how to get the values of `textField` in the `TextList` component.

A button is next to the `TextList` component in the View component. I will save all the `TextField` values when someone clicks the button.
I will post a network request in the `TextList` component to save the value to the backend.

I am using Redux. Does every `material-ui/TextField` should dispatch the `value` in the `onChange` callback function?

The `onChange` is at the bottom of this website:

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field

My central code:

`LabelTextField`:

```
  textChangeFun = (value) => {
    
  }


  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div style={{fontSize:0}}>
            <div style={inlineStyle}>
              <FlatButton  disableTouchRipple={true}  disabled={true} label={this.props.labelValue} />
            </div>
            <div  style={inlineStyle}>
              <TextField
                  hintText={this.props.textValue}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

`TextList`:

```
render(){
     return (
         <div>
           {demoData.map((item,id) =>
           <LabelTextField key={id} labelValue={item.label} textValue={item.text} ></LabelTextField>
             )}
         </div>
     )
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give LabelTextField a handler for the change event.

```
class LabelTextField extends React.Component {

  onChange(e) {
    this.props.onChange({ id: this.props.id, value: e.currentTarget.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div style={{fontSize:0}}>
            <div style={inlineStyle}>
              <FlatButton  disableTouchRipple={true}  disabled={true} label={this.props.labelValue} />
            </div>
            <div  style={inlineStyle}>
              <TextField
                  hintText={this.props.textValue}
                  onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class TextList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state.textFields = {}; // TODO: get initial state from demoData
    this.onTextFieldChange = this.onTextFieldChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTextFieldChange = ({ id, value }) {
    const { textFields } = this.state;
    textFields[id] = value;
    this.setState({ textFields }); 
  } 

  render(){
     return (
         <div>
           {demoData.map((item,id) =>
           <LabelTextField key={id} labelValue={item.label} textValue={item.text} onChange={this.onTextFieldChange} ></LabelTextField>
             )}
         </div>
     )
   }
}
```

This way any time a textField changes, it causes the `onTextFieldChange` handler to be called and the state of `TextList` to update.

If you have a more complicated situation, you might consider using redux or even http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/